# IDataErrorInfo not working when binding to child

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I have two xaml code line.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyEntity.Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

and

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EntityCollection}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyEntity.ChildEntity.NestedChildEntity}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyEntity.ChildEntity.ChildProperty, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
          SelectedValuePath="PK"/>
```

All my entities implements, through a base class, IDataErrorInfo and his indexer.

**MyEntity**, **ChildEntity** and **NestedChildEntity** are database entities. **MyEntity** has a navigation property to **ChildEntity**. 
**ChildEntity** has a navigation property to **NestedChildEntity**. 
**ChildProperty** is required in ChildEntity. **ChildProperty** is the Foreign Key and **NestedChildEntity** is the entity. If I don't select a value in the combobox, **ChildProperty** would be null and normally It can't be null.

**EntityCollection** is of type **List< NestedChildEntity >**

MyEntity.cs

```
public class MyEntity : BaseEntityClass
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long PK { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ChildEntity ChildEntity { get; set; }
}
```

ChildEntity.cs

```
public class ChildEntity : BaseEntityClass
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long PK { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long ChildProperty { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChildProperty")]
    public NestedChildEntity NestedChildEntity { get; set; }
}
```

NestedChildEntity.cs

```
public class NestedChildEntity : BaseEntityClass
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long PK { get; set; } 
}
```

BaseEntityClass.cs

```
public class BaseEntityClass : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            //Check the Required and StringLength attribute 
            var annotationValidationError = GetAnnotationValidationError(propertyName);

            if (annotationValidationError == null)
            {

                return GetValidationError(propertyName);
            }
            else
            {
                return annotationValidationError;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the first line, validation works, the indexer in my base class is reached and the property name is send as parameter (in this case, "Name")

For the second line, validation is never reach. Even if my **ChildEntity** class implements (through a base class) IDataErrorInfo.

Why such behaviour with a nested binding ? How can I workaround ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution.

Previously, in my view model constructor, I initialized my MyEntity property like so :

```
MyEntity = new MyEntity ();
```

The problem was that for my 
`{Binding Path=MyEntity.ChildEntity.ChildProperty}` , the **ChildEntity** in **MyEntity** was not initialized.

I changed the constructor to be like this :

```
MyEntity = new MyEntity { ChildEntity = new ChildEntity() };
```

and all works fine now !

thx for your help @mm8

Answer (score 0):

Why are you binding to both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`? The `SelectedValue` property will never be set.

This should work provided that the object returned by the `NestedChildEntity` property implements the `IDataErrorInfo` interface and that the type of this object matches the type of the items in the `EntityCollection`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EntityCollection}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyEntity.ChildEntity.NestedChildEntity, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Comment: I updated my question to a better understand. I use SelectedValue because I also use SelectedValuePath. I tried to put ValidatesOnDataErrors on SelectedItem like you suggest but it did nothing

Comment: So why are you then using SelectedItem? And what's the type of your properties?

Comment: To be honest, I know it's a little bit redundant but it's legacy code. The coder  did this to make sure that EntityFramework will not complain if only one of those property was set. EntityCollection = List<NestedChildEntity>. They are all POCOs except for **ChildProperty** who is a **long**

Comment: I improved the question

Comment: ChildEntity doesn't seem to implement the IDataErrorInfo?

Comment: I improved again the question and added the base class who implements IDataErrorInfo

Comment: Your issue is still not reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: By the way, the PK property has no attribute applied to it.

Comment: it seems that I have to publish almost all of my code to reproduce the problem... Thanks a lot for the help. I will find myself. Last question : For you, trying to validate property from parent objects in xaml should normally works?

Comment: The validation takes place in the class in which the property that you bind to is defined. The parent class doesn't validate properties of a child class.

Comment: I reword my question : Does the validation of a binded property should happen even if the binded target is a nested entity like in my example? (assuming that IDataErrorInfo is implemented for every entity)

Comment: Not the validation of the "parent" class, only the validation of the nested type.

Comment: So, that's my problem, validation doesn't happen for my nested type. Ok I'll come back with a solution

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my answer. Please accept it if your *question* has been answered.

Comment: You mentionned that I have to implement the IDataErrorInfo interface for the nested entity to make things work. The problem is that I already have IDataErrorInfo implemented for all my entities but validation doesn't happen when binding to a nested entity.

Comment: The validation in the child entity should work. Of course it is impossible to say why your code doesn't work without having seen (all of) it.